# Maven copy resources conditionally

Tags: maven

In my Web Application, I have some `.properties` and `.xml` files that are processed and copied from my `resources` directory into `classes`.

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

I have defined a variable in `pom.xml`:

```
<stage>Development</stage>
```

Now I want to copy some resources according to this variable. Basically:

- if `$stage` == `Development` --> copy
  `resources/logging-development.properties` to
  `classes/logging.properties`
- if `$stage` == `Production` --> copy
  `resources/logging-production.properties` to
  `classes/logging.properties`instead.

How can I achive this in my `pom.xml`?

(note - If possible, I am looking for a solution that does not require modifying the way maven is called by my IDE, so only modifications in pom.xml and the like)

NOTE: These are the only files that change from one environment to another

Comment: The long answer is "*use maven build profiles*". But the short answer may be: did you try `resources/logging-${stage}.properties` ?

Comment: Sorry, I am quite new to Maven, can you be more specific about how to specify that?

Comment: Sorry, I kind of overlooked that this is just about the resources configuration and not a file path that is being provided to a plugin. This is probably a case for using build profiles. Are the logging resources the only environment specific files you have or are there more?

Comment: I would use `copy-rename-maven-plugin`, attach it to `prepare-package` phase, and specify the source depending on your stage (as suggested by @Gimby). Better still, think if you really want 2 deliverables for the sake of different logging config. Better choose the config at runtime in the target environment.

Comment: What would be the difference of using `<phase>generate-sources</phase>` instead?

Comment: Copy does not depend on any other action, so both phases work in your case. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#. after giving it a thought, process-resources seems a good choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the pointers in the comments I was able to do it. It is simple, but works. It just copies the desired file to the right filename and then it is moved as usual. The files that are not desired are excluded from being moved. I leave here my solution in case it can help others:

```
<properties>
        <stage>Development</stage>
...
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-file</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceFile>src/main/resources/logging-${stage}.properties</sourceFile>
                        <destinationFile>src/main/resources/logging.properties</destinationFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
....
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>logging-Development.properties</exclude>
                <exclude>logging-Production.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
....
```